# At what point Vishnu ji takes incarnation?

Tags: vishnu, avatars

Vishnu ji takes incarnation whenever Dharma (Hinduism) is weakened to re-establish it. I want to know at what point he takes birth . What was the situation at the time of Mahabharata era and at other times he took birth ?

I am asking this we all are seeing constant decline of Hinduism in present world. Hinduism is losing its ground everywhere , demographic change is happening. Hindus are becoming atheists and disbelievers. Already we have lost many parts of land. There is not one country in the world left for hindus.

Comment: Mahabharata..  to understand the circumstance need to read srimad bhagavatam where gods pray to lord for birth in dwapara yuga .. As it was rampant with Kamsa in madhya bharatha, Jarasandha in magadha, Narakasura in prajyothisa (Assam). Duryodhana was just born he is kali purusa.. all this  suitation led krishna to be born. Another small Asuras kings where ruling either they are aligned with jarasandha or Asuras themselves like Salva prince, Sisupala and danta vakra, hidimba hamsa and debika.. ekalayva.. pundraka vasudeva. all the asura or raksha killed by krishna and bhima Take a list

Comment: Kamasa is rakshasa called kalaneimei in his previous birth. Jarasandha is viprachitti.. Jarasandha was having 95 odd prince arrested. who where going to be cornated across india. Planned to do narameda yagna for lord shiva. All the princess of those kingdown where kept in prison by narakasura or prajoythisa. Only few kingdom is left because. either they have the boon of shiva, surya. or Aligned with Jarasandha by pact like Mardha raja. out of few left out is hastinapur because bhisma and yadhava beign ruled by kamsa.. Jarasandha gave 2 of his  daughter in marriage to  Kamsa,

Comment: Please note that *dharma* is not Hinduism, but rather righteousness. It is also commonly known as truth.

Comment: @Harihara I know but truth always wins , it is law of universe . Vishnu needn't take avtara to protect truth.  Vishnu comes to earth or takes birth to save tradition and culture or Hinduism. Sanatam vedic dharma in society need to be protected. Without right culture existing , human society is like animals.